# Помогите определить тип предложения.

Tags: синтаксис

Когда заходит речь о людях, хороши они или плохи. я вспоминаю этот случай из детства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предложить такое решение;

"Когда заходит речь о людях, хороши они или плохи, я вспоминаю этот случай из детства".

Это СПП с последовательным подчинением, придаточное времени (союз КОГДА), придаточное изъяснительное (пропущена частица ЛИ в качестве союза).

Изъяснительное предложение служит для передачи косвенной речи в перестроенном виде.

Базовый вариант: "Когда заходит речь о том, хороши ли люди  или плохи, я вспоминаю этот случай из детства".